# The update from my AIF Webservice for SalesAgreementHeader [AX 2012] fails

Tags: c#, web-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

Hello I've created a query with only the `SalesAgreementHeader` as table. Then I used the wizard to create a document aif webservice. 
The webservice works fine, but the update always reports an "`Invalid xml document.`" error.
This error is thrown by the method `moveToNextElement` in the class `AxdBaseCreate`.

The reason for the exception is, that

```
reader.fieldName() = AgreementClassification
```

and

```
_expectedElementName = AgreementRelationType.
```

How can I fix this? Or is there any good way to debug this?

Before I created the query with only the `SalesAgreementHeader` I had an more complex query and had the same error. Then I created a new one and reduced it to only the `SalesAgreementHeader`.

**Update:**
A haven't solved the problem yet, but I think the problem could be because `SalesAgreementHeader` extends the `AgreementHeader` and the field `RelationType` is not visible in the AOS, but if you look directly in the DB.

**Update 2:**
This is the call stack:

[s]    \Classes\AxdBaseCreate\moveToNextElement                                                                9

[s]    \Classes\AxdBaseCreate\readSurrogateForeignKeyValue                                                    37

[s]    \Classes\AxdBaseCreate\readProperty                                                                    14

[s]    \Classes\AxdBaseCreate\readProperties                                                                 122

[s]    \Classes\AxdBaseUpdate\deserializeTopEntity                                                            25

[s]    \Classes\AxdBaseUpdate\deserializeDocument                                                            131

[s]    \Classes\AxdBaseUpdate\updateDocumentList                                                              42

[s]    \Classes\AxdBase\updateList                                                                            64

[s]    \Classes\AifDocumentService\updateList                                                                 34

[s]    \Classes\SalesAgreementService\update                                                                   4

Comment: I know this could be something you already know, but seeing the stacktrace I'm wondering if it is due to the fact there is a surrogate key instead of a natural key?

Comment: I think I made a step in the right direction. I changed the method `expandSurrogateForeignKeys` in the generated Class `AxdSalesAgreement` to return `false` and not `true`. Now I get new errors, but I hope I'll fix them by adding the Table `AgrremenHaeder` to the query.

Comment: The help for `expandSurrogateForeignKeys` is: "Gets a value that determines if surrogate key references will be replaced by fields from the natural key of the target table." In this case is the natural key empty.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide code which you're using?

I have an assumption (based on the name of AgreementRelationType it looks like this is Enim ) that you're trying to update field based on enum. If this is the case, then I hope I can help you.

When you need to update enum use following approach:

```
//here is an example how to change Status on SalesTable
//as you may see when you change the value of enum you have to set boolean autogenerated field to "true". 
//Name of such fields ends with suffix "Specified"
salesTable.SalesStatus = AxdEnum_SalesStatus.Invoiced;
salesTable.SalesStatusSpecified = true;
```

In advance I'd like to suggest you (in case you didn't do that) use following try..catch block. This will make your life easier.

```
try
{
    //your code here
}
catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException<SalesOrderDelete.SalesOrderDeleteTcpNet.AifFault> aifFaults) // This code catches error messages even when "Logging mode = Logging is disabled" on Inbound port
{
    SalesOrderDelete.SalesOrderDeleteTcpNet.InfologMessage[] infologMessageList = aifFaults.Detail.InfologMessageList;

    foreach (SalesOrderDelete.SalesOrderDeleteTcpNet.InfologMessage infologMessage in infologMessageList)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + infologMessage.Message + "\n");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to quit.\n");
    Console.ReadKey();
    cl.Abort();
}
```

Comment: I don't have the code anymore, because the concept changed and it was not needed to change the SalesAgreementHeader with the new concept. But your "catch" looks interesting, I think I can use parts of it in an other project. :)